# Where to start with this non-linear first order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I would like to study the following system non-linear ode system because I hope to gain some insight into the curvature of a related metric.
\begin{align}
(q'_1 + q'_2) &= \frac{2}{3}\big(A_1e^{-q_1} + Ce^{-(2q_1 + q_2)}\big) \\
q_2'(q_1' + q_2') &= 4\big(A_2e^{q_2} - Ce^{-(2q_1 + q_2)}\big)
\end{align}
where the $A_i$ and $C$ are constants and the functions $q_i = q_i(t)$ are real valued functions of one real variable.

Now I am a complete beginner when it comes to non-linear ode unfortunately and the literature on this topic is huge, hence I was wondering whether some expert eye may spot certain characteristics in these equations (e.g. whether they fall into a particular class of equations for which some technique is particularly useful) and point me to more targeted references? I would be totally happy about a recommendation like a chapter in one of the classics so that I know what I have to focus on.

Many thanks for the help!!

Comment: @amzoti yes, I've corrected it, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @GuidoKanschat absolutely, thanks! corrected it.

Comment: Could you provide some insight as to where this system originated?  You mentioned "curvature of a related metric"; that suggests a differential geometric context.  For example, I would be interested in knowing what metric etc.  It might help answer your question.  It might give a cue to the "expert eye".

Comment: @RobertLewis Sure, the above system originates from a study of the Einstein equation Ric$(g) = 0$ in the special case where one assumes an isometric action by a Lie group on the Einstein manifold, with orbit of real codimension one. This reduces the Einstein equations to a system of ODEs where the independent variable is a coordinate transverse to the group orbits. Hope this helps, just let me know in case more clarification is needed!